# Disabling Plesk Auto update for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plesk

Does anyone know how to disable auto updates across the whole server. I have several wordpress installations, which have been fine for years (some installed manually and some through the panel) and recently an upgrade to plesk has switched all the Wordpress installations to autoupdate, which is causing the config.php of each installation to become corrupted.

I can go through manually and restore from a back up for each, but were talking about a lot of  installations.

IS there a way to do turn this off, maybe at the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check auto updates settings on the following pages:

```
Tools & Settings > Application Vault > Update Settings
Applications > My Apps > Wordpress
```

Also there are the following command line options:

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/server_pref --update -aps-force-updates <true|false>
/usr/local/psa/bin/server_pref --update -aps-suggest-updates <true|false>
/usr/local/psa/bin/aps --install ... -aps-force-updates <true|false>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The first page they are both un checked - in the second there are just links to the different installations and no over all ability to switch off auto updates across the whole server. I am going to give this an upvote as it would solve the problem for some I think.

Comment: Each application has his own auto update option 'Update Settings /
Automatically update this app when updates are available' that is available on the application settings page. It is possibly you need to set up this option for existing applications only. New applications will be affected by settings on the 'Tools & Settings > Application Vault > Update Settings' page.

Comment: Thanks for that. I think that about covers it. I was also wondering what the options where on the command line - have you any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

**Configuring and Disabling Automatic WordPress Updates**

You can disable automatic updates in WordPress by adding this line of code in your wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );
```

However if you want to receive minor core updates, but disable theme and plugin updates, then you can do so by adding the following filters in your theme’s functions.php file or in a site-specific plugin.

Disable automatic WordPress plugin updates:

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_false' );
```

Disable automatic WordPress theme updates:

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_false' );
```

Now that you know how to disable automatic updates in WordPress, the question is should you disable it?

I hope it's helpful for you ..

Let me know if you have any concerns for the same.